# How to update data in SQLite table using php?

Tags: php, html, sql, sqlite

I am working on a php code as shown below:

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('database/Podcast.db');
    }
}
$db = new MyDB();

$f = $mp4_files[$_POST['id']];

$parts = pathinfo($f);

switch ($parts['extension']) {
        /* Conversion of mp4 into mp3 is happening */
}

print_r($f); // Line Z

$result = $db->exec("UPDATE Podcast_Export SET Status = 'Completed' WHERE House_number = '" . $f . "'"); // Line A

if ($result == FALSE) {
    echo "Error in fetch " . $db->lastErrorMsg(); // Line M
}
```

**At Line Z**, on console it prints **36031P.mp4** (When Go button is clicked from the **1st table row (from UI)**)

**At Line Z**, on console it prints **hello.mp**4 (When Go button is clicked from the **2nd table row(from UI)**)

**Problem Statement:**

I have a query at Line A in order to update **Podcast_Export** table but its not working and throwing error at Line M:

> ```
> Error in fetch database is locked
> ```

At this moment, I have the following content inside **Podcast_Export** table:

[image]

The **SQLite version** which I am using is **3.27.2**

Comment: question is that, where you will use these value after submit?`data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>"` its useless, if you are just using PHP

Comment: That's a good question. I think there is a slight mistake in my code. 
Remember, when new `mp4 files` come in directory, then the status should be `Go` in the `Podcast_Export` table and we added the following query:

`foreach ($mp4_files as $value) 
{ 
$count = $db->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Podcast_Export WHERE House_number = '".$value."'"); 
if($count <= 0){ 
$db->exec("INSERT INTO Podcast_Export (House_number,Status) 
VALUES ('".$value."', 'Go')"); 
} 
}`

When mp4 files are converted into mp3 then the Status should be Completed inside the Podcast_Export table.

Comment: its very difficult to understand.. u must need to share complete example

Comment: @devpro I have updated my question. Let me know how I can resolve that error.

Comment: @flash try to add  `$db->close();` and `unset($db); ` at the end of your script to release the OS file locks on the attached database files , maybe this is your problem .

Comment: Try moving the open code (`$db = new MyDB();`) to just before the update.  At the moment you open the database, do the conversion of the file (which may take a while) and then update.

Comment: Please check if the db file `Podcast.db` and directory `database` are writable.

Answer (score 0):

From the [php SQLITE3 doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php)

> SQLite3::exec — Executes a result-less query against a given database

It returns a boolean. "Resultless" query is typcially an  INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE but **not** a SELECT.

You might want to investigate how you could use [querySingle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.querysingle.php) to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the database is locked happened when you have an open DB process.
Check the following URL I hope to help you.

[Database locked while trying to access from PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866139/database-locked-while-trying-to-access-from-php-script/9866453)

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate of another question, then you can leave a comment.  An answer which merely points to another question adds very little.